# Как узнать, что именно не скопировалось из-за сбоя утилиты robocopy?

Tags: windows, администрирование

Запустил robocopy с такими параметрами:

```
robocopy "D:\1programming" "T:\1programming" /e /copyall /zb /V /TS /FP /ETA /TEE /LOG:C:\robocopy.txt /MIR
```

После работы команды вывелось, что произошел сбой 1 раз. Прикладываю скриншот. Как узнать, что именно не скопировалось? Я хочу докопировать это вручную через проводник.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотел попробовать эту команду в Power Shell:

```
$1 = Get-childitem "D:\1programming" -recurse
$2 = Get-childitem "T:\1programming" -recurse
Compare-Object $1 $2 -Property Name, Length
```

Но после первой же строчки выдалась ошибка, прикладываю скриншот.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как избежать этой ошибки? Мне кажется, что если я удалю папку, на которую ругается Power Shell, то он будет ругаться на другую папку.
Или если не избежать ошибки, то как еще можно узнать, что не скопировалось?

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть [сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Можно увидеть несколько опций для логирования.

Logging options

> **/v** - Produces verbose output, and shows all skipped files.

Если эта не поможет можно посмотреть в

**/move** которая оставит директории которые не скопировала

Comment: Я же использовал /v, посмотрите в моем вопросе.
/move не подходит, т.к. нужно именно копирование, а не перемещение.

Comment: А для теста и анализа можно посмотреть. И что в лог файле. Нет пропущенного каталога?

Comment: А как найти пропущенный? Я открывал блокнотом и искал "сбой", "ошибка", ничего не нашел, кроме сообщения, которое видно на скриншоте - там есть слово "СБОЙ".